# How to detect the first option in dropdown is clicked using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following dropdown in JSP.

```
<s:select name="select_group_id" list="act_list_group"
    listKey="group_id" listValue="group_name" headerValue="select_group_id"
    style="width: 130px" id="ms" multiple="true"/>
```

I would like to detect when the first option in dropdown is clicked.
I've tried as the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(function() {
    if(!$("#ms option:selected").length) {
        $("#ms option").attr("selected", "selected");
    }

    $('#ms').change(function() {

        $('#ms option:first').click(function(){
            //If user clicked the first(top) option in select box
            alert('first');
        });

        if(!$("#ms option:selected").length) {
            $("#ms").val($("#ms option:first").val());
            var selectedValue = $('#ms').val();
            var selectedText = $("#ms option[value='"+ selectedValue +"']").text();
            $(".ms-choice span").text(selectedText);
        }
        console.log($(this).val());
    }).multipleSelect({
        width: '130px',
        selectAll: false
    });
});
```

Any comments, pls.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

> Search for a given element from among the matched elements.

*Code*

```
var options = $("#ms option");
if(options.index($("#ms option:first") == options.index($("#ms option:selected"))
{
    //First one is selected
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My willing is if the user click **only** the first(top) option in select, all option is selected(if all option is no selected) and remove selected(if all option is selected). But, I don't know how to detect user click is the first option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="ms">
    <option> First</option>
    <option> Second</option>
    <option> Third</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$("#ms option:first").click(function(){
    alert("First option clicked");
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zo0u6x7/)**